Issue with displaying Marathi fonts correctly in dompdf
I'm encountering difficulties while trying to display Marathi fonts properly using dompdf. I've followed the usual steps for embedding custom fonts, but the Marathi characters aren't rendering as expected. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions for troubleshooting? Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Specifically, I'm using dompdf 2.0.7 and attempting to render Marathi text with Google fonts.
Thanks in advance for any help!
Html template code
php code
